# How do I stop parseFloat() from stripping zeroes to right of decimal

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a function that I'm using to remove unwanted characters (defined as currency symbols) from strings then return the value as a number. When returning the value, I am making the following call:

`return parseFloat(x);`

The problem I have is that when x == "0.00" I expect to get 0.00 (a float with two decimals) back. What I get instead is simply 0.

I've also tried the following:

`return parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);`

and still get simply 0 back. Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple:

```js
function decimalPlaces(float, length) {
  ret = "";
  str = float.toString();
  array = str.split(".");
  if (array.length == 2) {
    ret += array[0] + ".";
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (i >= array[1].length) ret += '0';
      else ret += array[1][i];
    }
  } else if (array.length == 1) {
    ret += array[0] + ".";
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      ret += '0'
    }
  }

  return ret;
}
console.log(decimalPlaces(3.123, 6));
```

Comment: i think this is the solution because you need a string for the print, not a number because i think for you 3.00 == 3 but you want to print the number with 2 decimal places.

Comment: it doesn't round ? if 2.009 should be 2.01

Comment: returns a string

Comment: Sure it returns a string, you can't have additional decimal places for a number type. This is a formatted version of a number. Also rounding is not the responsibility of this function. If you need it, you can add it.

Answer (score 24):

parseFloat() turns a string into a floating point number. This is a binary value, not a decimal representation, so the concept of the number of zeros to the right of the decimal point doesn't even apply; it all depends on how it is formatted back into a string. Regarding toFixed, I'd suggest converting the floating point number to a Number:

```
new Number(parseFloat(x)).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: If x = `2.00` or `'2.00'`, you still get the string representation `'2.00'`.

Comment: @ConAntonakos - Well, yes, that's the point. You can't have "trailing zeros" in a floating point value, only in the string representation of the value.

Comment: I realize, but I was hoping that you could retain the floating point without needing to force it to a string. :(

Comment: @ConAntonakos - If you just want a floating point number, just use `parseFloat(x)` directly, without anything else. If you want a `Number` object, use `new Number(parseFloat(x))`. If you want a string representation to a fixed number of decimal places, use the answer. It's only the string representation that provides for the "trailing zeroes to right of decimal" that OP needed.

Answer (score 13):

this should work:

```
return parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
```

you can test it by running this in firebug:

```
var x = '0.00';
alert(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: @Ted Hopp - Regardless of what the OP states, I've tried it in IE 8, Safari, Firebug and the Chrome JS Console, I'm giving Victor the +1 for this, as it's correct at least as far as I can test.

Comment: @jball - I agree...it should work, but it doesn't. I was hoping someone had seen similar behavior before and could give me a heads up as to why it might not.

Comment: @jball - Good to know. I would have expected js to autobox a primitive float in a Number in order to call toFixed, but maybe whatever environment OP is using is a little weird.

Comment: +1 This should work. Although, what would happen with lets say "0.000"?

Comment: @OP what environment are you using? Does it fail across all browsers? do you get an error?

Comment: @JCOC611 `toFixed` is pretty literal, I expect it would chop off anything after the given place. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) agrees.

Comment: @Victor: I think it will return 0.00 not 0.000, @jball: oh, ok!

Comment: btw are you expecting a number or a string returned?? in chrome a string is returned..

Comment: @JCOC611 it always returns a string.

Comment: yup I just figured what the OP wanted to do...well in that case "0.1" would return "0.10", it might be ok, but just pointing it out...

Comment: this returns a string, not a number

Comment: @TabethaMoe - Of course it does. The only way OP gets to keep "trailing zeroes to right of decimal" is with a string representation. Nothing else makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, I had this issue as I wanted to parse the `onChange` value of a textField into a float, so as the user typed I could update my model.

The problem was with the decimal place and values such as `12.120` would be parsed as `12.12` so the user could never enter a value like `12.1201`.

The way I solved it was to check to see if the **STRING** value contained a decimal place and then split the string at that decimal and then count the number of characters after the place and then format the float with that specific number of places.

To illustrate:

```
const hasDecimal = event.target.value.includes(".");
const decimalValue = (hasDecimal ? event.target.value.split(".") : [event.target.value, ""])[1];
const parsed = parseFloat(event.target.value).toFixed(decimalValue.length);
const value = isNaN(parsed) ? "" : parsed;
onEditValue(value);
```

Comment: Obvious reminder to make sure your value is coming in as a string if you're not grabbing this out of the event.  has a 0 number sneak though and broke once it got to QA

Answer (score 1):

Here is dynamic version of floatParser for those who need

```
function customParseFloat(number){
  if(isNaN(parseFloat(number)) === false){
    let toFixedLength = 0;
    let str = String(number);

    // You may add/remove seperator according to your needs
    [".", ","].forEach(seperator=>{
      let arr = str.split(seperator);
      if( arr.length === 2 ){
        toFixedLength = arr[1].length;
      }
    })

    return parseFloat(str).toFixed(toFixedLength);
  }

  return number; // Not a number, so you may throw exception or return number itself
}
```