# ParseFloat a string and retain zeroes in decimal part

Tags: php, floating-point

I have a problem, I found this [JavaScript parseFloat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868556/how-do-i-stop-parsefloat-from-stripping-zeroes-to-right-of-decimal), but thats not a solution I need.

I have f.e. string `48.453150 E`, and I need just float number from that, when I use `(float)`, it will return `48.45315`, but I need to retain zeroes at the end of decimal part. I dont know, how many digits will be in the decimal part, it can be various.

Is there some way, to parse float string and retain that zeroes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use simple function, and its working well:

```
function get_number($str) {
    $number = '';

    $allowed = array('.');

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        $allowed[] = (string)$i;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        if (in_array($str{$i}, $allowed)) {
            $number .= $str{$i};
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return $number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you parse the number as a float, it's not a string, so the concept of trailing digits doesn't make sense.

When you want to display the number, use `number_format($number, 5)` to convert it to a string with 5 digits after the decimal point. This will include trailing zeroes.

Comment: but I dont know, how many digits will be after decimal point, I need the same, as it was in the original string.

Comment: Then don't convert it to a float in the first place, use the string.

Comment: Maybe you're right, maybe better will be to walk-through whole string, and stop when non-number and decimal point is reached.