# Convert javaScript floating point numbers to string without loosing insignificant trailing zeros

Tags: formatting, numbers

when converting javascript floating point numbers to string format insignificant trailing decimal zeros are lost.

for an example

var num = 20.0;
altert(num);

will give output as 20

how can i stop removing insignificant decimal trailing zeros when formatted as string

Answer (score 0):

[Answer that was already given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868556/how-do-i-stop-parsefloat-from-stripping-zeroes-to-right-of-decimal)

Please take above reference