# Convert JavaScript string which is a decimal number to number without loosing trailing zeros

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a string that is a decimal number to a number without losing the zeros at the end

[Convert javaScript floating point numbers to string without loosing insignificant trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554276/convert-javascript-floating-point-numbers-to-string-without-loosing-insignifican) solution here returns a string, not a number

```
let myNumber = '0.10'
parseFloat(myNumber) // 0.1
parseFloat(myNumber).toFixed(2) // "0.10"
Number(parseFloat(myNumber).toFixed(2)) // 0.1

Desired output - convertToNumber('0.10') -> 0.10
```

Comment: if you want "0.10" in javascript it HAS to be a string ... because a number is a number - i.e. `0.1` is the value `0.1` there is no "stringiness" to it

Comment: number values in js will only carry the minimum precision required to represent that value. as a result, number values will not include redundant trailing "0"'s

Comment: Why would you need the 0 as number anyways? It only fits for displaying, and you can display as a string. If you need to do calculations, it doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

I think if you were to create a Number object the only value that it could be is .1. This is done within the number class, so I do not think you can change this