# jQuery - unable to convert string to number using parseFloat

Tags: jquery

This should be a very easy and quick one, but I don't understand why this is not working.

I'm trying to convert a string ("50.0") to a number using `parseFloat()`

This is the code:

```
 // Lets say e.value = 20
 var valueStr = e.value + '.0';   // valueStr = "20.0";           
 value = parseFloat(valueStr);
 console.log (value);
```

I am expecting `value` to be 20.0, but it returns 20.

I've checked [this example](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/02/jquery-convert-string-to-float-double.html) and it does exactly the same thing, but it works in the example.

Here's a codepen with the full code (i'm modifying a jquery plugin called "[roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com/)")

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPyxyv

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are looking for [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). `parseFloat(valueStr).toFixed(1);`  you can also look at this question and the corresponding answers:  [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: that worked, on the console. Not as the plugin value but i'm guessing there's something else blocking it to be displayed as .0 value. Thanks for the help

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868556/how-do-i-stop-parsefloat-from-stripping-zeroes-to-right-of-decimal

Comment: But whats the Problem. You want to display it, then as a string?

Comment: The first comment solved this question, it was returning as a number without .0 at the end