# Add thousand separator with JavaScript on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

I am using the following JavaScript function to add thousand separator for a input number on **keyup** event.

```
$("#inputId").on('keyup', function(evt){
    if (evt.which != 110 && evt.which != 190){ 
        var n = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\,/g,''),10);             
        $(this).val(n.toLocaleString());
    }
});
```

Most of the cases this function is working as expected, but the only issue is the input field does not accept zero after the decimal point (for example 10.**0**1) but it does accept numbers like 10.**2**5 . I can't figure out the reason for this behavior. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: parsing would remove the `0`, since which doesn't have any value `1.0` => `1`

Comment: What does `parseFloat(x,10)` do? [MDN says it has only one argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: `parseFloat` doesn't have any radix argument.... so adding second argument doesn't make any sense

Comment: Out of curiosity, What exactly is a thousand separator ?

Comment: Yes that is a mistake, I have mistaken **parseFloat** with **parseInt**. But is there way to change this function to accept a value like 10.01?

Comment: @FlyingGambit **toLocaleString()** will add the thousand separator(for me ",").

Comment: I don't see any reason why an Input field would not allow you to enter 10.01

Comment: According to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868556/how-do-i-stop-parsefloat-from-stripping-zeroes-to-right-of-decimal] it is the default behavior of **parseFloat()**, by adding **toFixed(2)** will allow to enter a zero after decimal point. but fail on **toLocaleString()**.

Comment: I understood the problem, Pranav is right, its because of the `0`

Answer (score 4):

Splitting on the decimal would work. Something like this. Note this is very basic starting point and does not account for the different separators in other countries/systems (ie: 10.000,00)

```js
<script>
var myinput = document.getElementById('myinput');

myinput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var val = this.value;
  val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
  
  if(val != "") {
    valArr = val.split('.');
    valArr[0] = (parseInt(valArr[0],10)).toLocaleString();
    val = valArr.join('.');
  }
  
  this.value = val;
});

</script>
```

```html
<input id="myinput" type="text'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and seems like it is working for my case.

Comment: @creative after the 15 digits entered values become zero. what is the reason ??