# How to add comma in a number in string

Tags: javascript

So I know how to add a comma on numbers (toLocaleString.()) and this function requires integer or decimal value as a parameter. I need this result with 2 digit decimal value. It does run and return me correct data but I want decimal to be fixed to 2 digits like below

```js
var num = 66666.7
console.log("original", num)
console.log("with comma", num.toLocaleString())
console.log("with 2 digit fixed", num.toFixed(2))
console.log("not working--", (num.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString())
console.log("error--", (num.toLocaleString()).toFixed(2))
```

It doesn't work with toFixed() values
Suggest anything, please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the exact number of decimal digits in your options, which is the second parameter in `toLocaleString()`

```
const number = 24242324.5754;

number.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
})

// result is: 24,242,324.58
```

See also MDN doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

> **minimumFractionDigits**
>
> The minimum number of fraction digits to use.
>   Possible values are from 0 to 20; the default for plain number and
>   percent formatting is
>
> **maximumFractionDigits**
>
> The maximum number of fraction digits to use.
>   Possible values are from 0 to 20; the default for plain number
>   formatting is the larger of minimumFractionDigits and 3

Comment: Cheers. There are tons of other options you can use. Just take a look at the MDN doc.

Answer (score 1):

I think toFixed() is changing the float to string.

```
num = 66666.7;
num = parseFloat(num.toFixed(2))
console.log(num.toLocaleString())
```

Following solution should work fine.

Edit - There is another solution for this

```
(Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: no. I want decimal up to 2 places. it doesn't add 0 along with .7

Comment: Thats the equivalent of `num.toLocalString()`

Answer (score 1):

The [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method returns a string but the [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method expects a number so just convert your string to a number after using the `toFixed()` method with the [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function and then use the `toLocaleString()` method on it.

However, do note that you will have to manually append the leading `0` since the `parseFloat()` method removes any leading zeroes to the right of the decimal point.

Check this [particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4868643/4114907) on another Stack Overflow thread that explains the reason why the `parseFloat()` method removes the leading zeroes after the decimal point.

---

```js
var num = 66666.7
var parsedNum = (""+num).split('.')[1].length > 1 ?
    parseFloat(num.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString() : 
    parseFloat(num.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString() + '0';

console.log("original", num)
console.log("with comma", num.toLocaleString())
console.log("with 2 digit fixed", num.toFixed(2))
console.log("now working--", parsedNum)
```

Comment: but it will fail when there is already 2 digit no i.e 66666.79

Comment: @pu You can just check if the number has more than one digit or not after the decimal point and append the 0 only if it does. Check the updated answer.