# Returning 0 when transforming string information inside a useState into parseFloat

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
import * as C from './styles';


import AddButton from '../../components/AddButton';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useApi } from '../../hooks/useApi';


const AddProduct = () => {
    const api = useApi();

    const [apiCategories, setApiCategories] = useState<any[]>([]);

    const [isCreate, setIsCreate] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const [name, setName] = useState<string>('');
    const [price, setPrice] = useState<number>(0);
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState<string>('');
    const [stock, setStock] = useState<number>(0);
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState<string>('');

    const [priceSTR, setPriceSTR] = useState<string>('');
    const [stockSTR, setStockSTR] = useState<string>('');

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const category = async () => {
          const categories = await api.getCategories();
          setApiCategories(categories);
        }
        category();
      }, []);  
    
    const onSubmit = async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const priceFLT = parseFloat(priceSTR);
            const stockINT = parseInt(stockSTR);
            setPrice(priceFLT);
            setStock(stockINT);
            setLoading(false);
            await api.postProduct(name, price, desc, stock, categories);
            setIsCreate(true);
            setError(false);
            setName('');
            setDesc('');
            setPriceSTR('');
            setStockSTR('');    
        } catch (err) {
            setError(true);
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

  return (
    <C.Container>
        <C.Post>
            <C.Input 
                placeholder='Product name'
                value={name}
                onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
        </C.Post> 
        <C.Post>
            <C.Desc 
                placeholder='Simple desc...'
                value={desc}
                onChange={e => setDesc(e.target.value)}
            />
        </C.Post>
        <C.Post>
            <C.Input 
                placeholder='Price'
                value={priceSTR}
                onChange={e => setPriceSTR(e.target.value)}
            />
        </C.Post>
        <C.Post>
            <C.Input 
                placeholder='Stock'
                value={stockSTR}
                onChange={e => setStockSTR(e.target.value)}
            />
        </C.Post>
        <C.Post>
            <C.Categories 
                onChange={(e) => setCategories(e.target.value)}
            >
                <option value="Todas categorias">Choose a category</option>
                {apiCategories.map(category => {
                return (
                    <option value={`${category.name}`}>{category.name}</option>
                )
                })}
            </C.Categories>
        </C.Post>
        <C.Add>
            <AddButton 
                children='Send'
                type='submit'
                onClick={onSubmit}
            />
        </C.Add>
        {isCreate ? (
            <p id='check'>Product Created!</p>
        ) : null} 
        {error ? (
            <p id='error'>Error!</p>
        ) : null} 
    </C.Container>
  )
}

export default AddProduct
```

My real purpose is to get the information from these inputs and send it to the "useApi" hook to validate the registration of a new product. However, the "price" and "stock" states in the API must be sent as float and int respectively, but I would like to get the information in string to then transform to float and int, and then send it to the API. It's what I try to do with

```
const priceFLT = parseFloat(priceSTR);
const stockINT = parseInt(stockSTR);
setPrice(priceFLT);
setStock(stockINT);
```

I can ship, but the stock and price always ends up as "0". How can I solve this problem?

ps: I would like to get this information in string in the input to be able to use placeholder and to be able to use "." to set a price.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop parseFloat() from stripping zeroes to right of decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868556/how-do-i-stop-parsefloat-from-stripping-zeroes-to-right-of-decimal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to update a state for price or stock to provide it to your api call

```
        ...
        const priceFLT = parseFloat(priceSTR);
        const stockINT = parseInt(stockSTR);
        setLoading(false);
        await api.postProduct(name, priceFLT, desc, stockINT, categories);
        ...
```

setPrice or setStock are asynchronous, so the update is not immediate, that is partially why you end up with 0 (the default value) when you try to immediately use `price` or `stock` variables (another more complex reason is due to the way useState and reference work, once updated the `price` variable inside the onSubmit that has been called is not the same as the `price` variable that has been updated)